# ¿Cómo procesar el valor anterior de un registro en fila actual sin iterrows()?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un `DataFrame` con más de 5000 artículos y tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
|idfecha | idarticulo | demanda | devoluciones | stock_total|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|    0   |     10     |  1.26   |    0.15      |    162     |
|    1   |     10     |  10.80  |    0.76      |    162     |
|    2   |     10     |  5.20   |    0.38      |    162     |
|    3   |     10     |  3.50   |    0.25      |    162     |
|    4   |     10     |  4.60   |    0.33      |    162     |
```

para fines prácticos sólo usaré un articulo.

Mi objetivo es dar de alta y llenar dos campos: (`stock_inicial` y `stock_final`) con el siguiente criterio:

**stock_inicial** = `stock_final` del registro anterior. Exceptuando idfecha = 0, para ese registro solo es igual a `stock_total`.

**stock_final** = `stock_inicial - demanda + devoluciones`

Sólo pude hacerlo utilizando `iterrows()`, pero tarda mucho tiempo en finalizar la tarea (10minutos):

```
data = [
        [0, 10, 1.26, 0.15, 162], 
        [1, 10, 10.8, 0.76, 162], 
        [2, 10, 5.2, 0.38, 162], 
        [3, 10, 3.5, 0.25, 162], 
        [4, 10, 4.6, 0.33, 162]]

columns = ['idfecha','idarticulo','demanda','devoluciones','stock_total']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data,columns=columns)



df = df.sort_values('idfecha')
for index,row in df.iterrows():

    if index == 0:

        df['stock_inicial'] = df['stock_total']

    else:
        df.loc[index,'stock_inicial'] = df.loc[index-1,'stock_final']

    df['stock_final'] = df['stock_inicial'] - df['demanda'] + df['devoluciones']
```

Llegando al `DataFrame` con el resultado esperado:

```
display(df)

|idfecha | idarticulo | demanda | devoluciones | stock_total | stock_inicial |  stock_final  |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    0   |     10     |  1.26   |    0.15      |     162     |     162.00    |    160.89     |
|    1   |     10     |  10.80  |    0.76      |     162     |     160.89    |    150.85     |
|    2   |     10     |  5.20   |    0.38      |     162     |     150.85    |    146.03     |
|    3   |     10     |  3.50   |    0.25      |     162     |     146.03    |    142.78     |
|    4   |     10     |  4.60   |    0.33      |     162     |     142.78    |    138.51     |
```

Mi idea es tratar de utilizar las operaciones vectoriales que ofrece `pandas`, para reducir el tiempo de ejecución. Estuve leyendo métodos como `shift`, `diff` y `rolling` que hacen cosas parecidas, pero no tuve éxito, solo unos cuantos NaN's sin resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma sencilla:

```
df["stock_final"] = df.stock_total[0] + (-df.demanda + df.devoluciones).cumsum()
df["stock_inicial"] = df.stock_final.shift(1).fillna(df.stock_total[0])
```

Detalle:

- Calculamos primero el `stock_final` que es la suma acumulada de `(-df.demanda + df.devoluciones)`
- Y el `stock_inicial` siempre es el `stock_final` anterior, salvo en el primer caso que será el primer valor `df.stock_total[0]`